# Capturing printer data stream in ruby

Tags: ruby, printing, data-stream, redmon

anyone knows where a printer data stream is stored, and how to capture it a ruby executable? (for later pdf conversion for example)

I'm questioning this one, related to another question of mine. [So transparent that i can't catch it...Using Rghost to emulate ghostscript command as would be on virtual printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405655/so-transparent-that-i-cant-catch-it-using-rghost-to-emulate-ghostscript-comma)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend on your OS.  It looks like Windows above.  What I usually do in a situation like this is use procmon to capture all of the system calls and then hunt through the output to find the call I'm looking for.  It's a bit like looking for a particular packet in a network trace.

Procmon is the windows tool I use.  It can be found here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx