# Sending ghostscript output file directly into ruby executable

Tags: exe, stdin, ghostscript

i'm trying to convert on windows 7 stdin to pdf using ghostscript, and instead of generating a local file, i want to send this file directly to my exe file.

I'm doing this

```
C:\Programas\gs\gs9.05\bin\gswin64c.exe -IC:\Programas\gs\gs9.05\lib;C:\Programas\gs\fonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -r300 -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sOutputFile=%%pipe%%"C:\Projectos\Online File Manager\Codigo\Ruby\shoes apps\FileCreate7.exe"
```

(I've meanwhile put the exe inside a cmd file)

I'm getting the error :

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: **** Could not open the file %pipe%c:\tempRep\filecreate.cmd .
Unrecoverable error: ioerror in setdevice
Operand stack:
    --nostringval--
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't do this. The pdfwrite device opens the output stream as 'seekable' which clearly isn't compatible with a pipe or other similar construct. You need to have a local file.

Comment: Hi @KenS, I can do that, but how could i automatically invoke my exe - or cmd - file to read the pdf? Any ideas ? (this question relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405655/so-transparent-that-i-cant-catch-it-using-rghost-to-emulate-ghostscript-comma) Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I know absolutely nothing about Ruby, and I'm not really sure what you mean here. If you are forking a process to run Ghostscript you can have your executable read the PDF file when the process ends.

Comment: Well, i tried at first running a .cmd (or .bat) file with two lines. On the first line i would call gs writing the pdf to a file. On the second line i would call my app. The problem is that the app didn't run, only gs got executed...Why won't my second line of the batch file run ?

Comment: Without seeing the script I can't really comment. I have used scripts (on Linux) and Windows Command Shell commands myself so I know there's nothing unique about Ghostscript which prevents this working.